# "Not find OracleMTSRecoveryService" というエラーで Oracle Database のインストールが失敗する

Tags: database, oracle

私はOracle Database 11g release 2 (11.2.0.3)をインストールしたいと思っています。
しかし、インストール時にNot find OracleMTSRecoveryServiceは見つかりませんでした。というエラーが表示されます。
私はどの様な対応をすればよろしいのでしょうか。

リポート：
私は過去にこれをアンインストールしています。理由はインストールに失敗したと判断してしまった事からです。
アンインストールするために、アンインストーラーを使用していません。
ファイルの削除、レジストリーキーの削除で対応をしています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このサイト ([**ja**.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) は Stack Overflow ([stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、[Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/3054) をご覧ください。つまり、このサイトへの投稿は日本語話者にしかリーチしませんので、英訳を付ける必要はありません。英語部分は編集でカットさせていただきました。英語で広く回答を募りたい場合は、[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) へ新しく英語の質問を投稿する必要があります。[履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/49407/revisions)に英語部分は残っていますのでご安心下さい。

Comment: すみません。今気づきました。修正ありがとうございます。